# Facebuilder Rig not working properly

Tags: rigging, armature

I created a head object by using Facebuilder and joined with a body downloaded from Mixamo. However, when i try to rotate my head, it stays in the same location.

Appreciated if someone can solve this issue.

[image: Rig works well in body parts]

[image: The head does not move with the body]

Comment: Hello, have you checked the weights in Weight Paint mode? Also make sure that the Deform option of the head bone is activated. You can share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The file is larger than 24mb(Approx. 115mb). Can I still upload it through the link?

Comment: you can use another platform

Answer (score 0):

It seems your head is not weight painted, so you have to check it out.
Here is what I would do :

Select your armature, go to **Edit Mode** and find the name of the bones to which your head should be parented to.
Then, back to **Object Mode**, select your mesh, go to **Edit Mode** and select any vertex on the head.

Press **N**, and in the menu that should appear on the top right corner, select **item** and under **Vertex Weights** check the weights assigned to this vertex.
If it's weight painted, you should see a value higher than 0 assigned to the head bone. (Ideally, 1 if you want the bone to have full control over this vertex).

[image]

You could see this directly in Weight Paint mode but this method allows you to see every weight assigned to a vertex without having to check all the bones 1 by 1.
If the value is 0, then you must weight paint your head.

To do that, go to **Object Mode**, select your armature, **Shift+LMB** to select your mesh as well, and go to Weight Paint mode.
Click on the head bone, and all the areas of your mesh under this bone should display colour different from blue.
Then, set your weight on 1, and paint your head.

Once you're done, in the top left menu, under **Weight**, select **Smooth** and set how many times you want to smooth it out in the bottom left corner to have a nice transition with the neck bone.